# Prove $|\Delta y(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}x(1-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We have boundary value problem: $$y'' = g(x),\; y(0)=y(1)=0$$
and the solution: $$y(x) = \int_{0}^{1}G(x, \xi)g(\xi)d\xi$$
with: $$G(x,\xi) = \begin{cases} \xi(x-1) & \text{for } 0 \leq \xi \leq x \leq 1 \\ x(\xi-1)) & \text{for } \ 0\leq x \leq \xi \leq 1\end{cases}$$
If we replace $g(x)$ by $g(x) + \Delta g(x)$ with $|\Delta g(x)| \leq \epsilon$, then the solution $y(x)$ will change to $y(x) + \Delta y(x)$. Prove: $$|\Delta y| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}x(1-x)\; \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 $$

I don't know where to begin, except I know that 
$$|\Delta y(x)| = \left|\int_{0}^{1}G(x,\xi)\Delta g(\xi)d\xi\right| $$
$$\leq\left|\int_{0}^{1}G(x,\xi) \epsilon d\xi \right|$$
So, can someone show me how prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last integral,

$$\leq\left|\int_{0}^{1}G(x,\xi) \epsilon d\xi \right| = \epsilon \left|(x-1)\int_0^x\xi d\xi  + x\int_x^1(1-\xi)d\xi\right| =\epsilon \left|(x-1)\frac{x^2}{2}  + x\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2} +x\right)\right| =\epsilon x(1-x)/2 \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8} $$

Comment: Oh, I thought of that way, but I think it's just a mess; so, I decided not to do that. But, after you did, it turned out to be the right way, and not as I think. Thank you a lot!